# F# array with O(1) lookup and O(1) slice

Tags: arrays, f#, functional-programming, slice

I need an Array-like data structure that supports

```
a.[i]
```

in time O(1) and

```
a.[i..j]
```

also in time O(1).

O(1) updates are *not* a requirement. Really, all I need is a constant Array with a notion of in-place slice or subarray.

I could of course construct such a thing from `Array`, but I'd be happier if I could use one that already existed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The .NET standard library has the type [`ArraySegment<'T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) for this purpose. Unfortunately it doesn't have the methods `Item` and `GetSlice` that allow you to use the `.[x]` and `.[x..y]` syntaxes, respectively. But you can add them with an augmentation:

```
type System.ArraySegment<'T> with

    member this.Item(x) =
        if x < 0 || x >= this.Count then
            raise (System.IndexOutOfRangeException("Index was outside the bounds of the array segment."))
        this.Array.[x + this.Offset]

    member this.GetSlice(start: int option, finish : int option) =
        let start = defaultArg start 0
        let finish = defaultArg finish (this.Count - 1)
        if start < 0 || finish >= this.Count then
            raise (System.IndexOutOfRangeException("Index was outside the bounds of the array segment."))
        new ArraySegment<'T>(this.Array, this.Offset + start, finish - start + 1)
```